# If the input to the autoencoder is normalized, do we need to use sigmoid on the last layer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, sigmoid

According to:
[Why is the decoder in an autoencoder uses a sigmoid on the last layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307833/why-is-the-decoder-in-an-autoencoder-uses-a-sigmoid-on-the-last-layer)

- The last layer activation function contains `sigmoid` in order to the output to be in range [0, 1].
- If the input to the autoencoder is normalized (each pixel between [0..1]), Can we change the activation function of the last layer from `sigmoid` to be something else ?

- Can we use no activation function at all ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of output do you want since even though it's "autoencoder" you don't really need to have the input and the output to be the same.

Comment: But if you want to have 0-1 output then yes, better use sigmoid. You'll have a very hard time training them to be in such tiny range out of everything `float32` can be if you don't use any activation.

Comment: But on the other hand if you want output to be integer then you don't really need activation function. Maybe `relu` will do something useful if you want to have only positive output but that's about it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).